# Getting stuck in precapture sequence

Tags: android, android-camera2

At the moment, I'm trying to create a camera Fragment, based on the Camera2Basic example. The major differences are the possibility, that the user can switch between flash modes (auto, on, off) and that a preview of the taken still capture is shown, so the user can decide if the taken picture should be saved or discarded.
Problems arise, when using the flash in always on mode. Sometimes, the precapture sequence doesn't complete and the app is stuck. The preview still works and the UI is responsive, but processing reaches an 'infinite loop'.
According to Camera2Basic, I'm using this CaptureCallback.

```
private CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback mPreviewCaptureCallback =
    new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {
        private int counter = 0; // Counts failed attempts to gain AF or complete precapture
            @Override
            public void onCaptureCompleted(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session, @NonNull CaptureRequest request, @NonNull TotalCaptureResult result) {
                process(result);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCaptureProgressed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session, @NonNull CaptureRequest request, @NonNull CaptureResult partialResult) {
                process(partialResult);
            }

            private void process(CaptureResult result) {
                Integer aeState = result.get(CaptureResult.CONTROL_AE_STATE);
                Integer afState = result.get(CaptureResult.CONTROL_AF_STATE);
                switch (mState) {
                    case STATE_PREVIEW:
                        // Do nothing
                        break;
                    case STATE_WAIT_LOCK:
                        if (afState == null) {
                            counter = 0;
                            captureStillImage();
                        } else if (afState == CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_STATE_FOCUSED_LOCKED ||
                                afState == CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_STATE_NOT_FOCUSED_LOCKED) {
                            if (aeState == null ||
                                    aeState == CaptureResult.CONTROL_AE_STATE_CONVERGED) {
                                mState = STATE_PICTURE_CAPTURED;
                                captureStillImage();
                            } else {
                                runPrecaptureSequence();
                            }
                            counter = 0;
                        } else if(counter > 50) {
                            counter = 0;
                            restartFocus();
                        } else {
                            counter++;
                            Log.d(TAG, "STATE_WAIT_LOCK - Counter : " + counter);
                        }
                        break;
                    case STATE_WAIT_PRECAPTURE:
                        if (aeState == null ||
                                aeState == CaptureResult.CONTROL_AE_STATE_PRECAPTURE ||
                                aeState == CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_STATE_FLASH_REQUIRED) {
                            mState = STATE_WAIT_NON_PRECAPTURE;
                        }
                        break;
                    case STATE_WAIT_NON_PRECAPTURE:
                        if (aeState == null || aeState != CaptureResult.CONTROL_AE_STATE_PRECAPTURE) {
                            mState = STATE_PICTURE_CAPTURED;
                            captureStillImage();
                        } else if (counter > 50) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "STATE_WAIT_NON_PRECAPTURE - Restart");
                            counter = 0;
                            restartPrecapture();
                        } else {
                            counter++;
                            Log.d(TAG, "STATE_WAIT_NON_PRECAPTURE - Counter : " + counter);
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }
        };
```

As I encountered a similiar issue in the past with AF not getting locked, I created a method to restart AF.

```
private void restartFocus() {
    try {
        mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(
                CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER,
                CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER_CANCEL);

        mCaptureSession.capture(
                mPreviewRequestBuilder.build(),
                mPreviewCaptureCallback,
                mBackgroundHandler);

        lockFocus();
    } catch (CameraAccessException cae) {
        cae.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void lockFocus() {
    try {
        mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(
                CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER,
                CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER_START);
        mState = STATE_WAIT_LOCK;
        mCaptureSession.capture(
                mPreviewRequestBuilder.build(),
                mPreviewCaptureCallback,
                mBackgroundHandler);
    } catch (CameraAccessException cae) {
        cae.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

So I decided to use this idea a second time and restart the precapture sequence.

```
private void restartPrecapture() {
    try {
        mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(
                CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_PRECAPTURE_TRIGGER,
                CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_PRECAPTURE_TRIGGER_CANCEL);
        mCaptureSession.capture(mPreviewRequestBuilder.build(),
                mPreviewCaptureCallback,
                mBackgroundHandler);

        runPrecaptureSequence();
    } catch (CameraAccessException cae) {
        cae.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void runPrecaptureSequence() {
    try {
        setFlash(mPreviewRequestBuilder);
        mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_PRECAPTURE_TRIGGER,
                CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_PRECAPTURE_TRIGGER_START);
        mState = STATE_WAIT_PRECAPTURE;
        mCaptureSession.capture(mPreviewRequestBuilder.build(),
                mPreviewCaptureCallback,
                mBackgroundHandler);
    } catch (CameraAccessException cae) {
        cae.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Inspecting Logcat showed, that the app sometimes gets stuck in STATE_WAIT_NON_PRECAPTURE, while aeState remains CaptureResult.CONTROL_AE_STATE_PRECAPTURE. If the counter reaches 50 in this state, *restartPrecapture()* is called, as intended.
At the moment I only encounter this problem when using CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON_ALWAYS_FLASH, but sometimes I take dozens of pictures before this occurs, so maybe with auto or disabled flash, the chances are much smaller.

```
private void setFlash(CaptureRequest.Builder requestBuilder) {
    switch(mFlashMode) {
        case FLASH_AUTO:
            setFlashAuto(requestBuilder);
            break;
        case FLASH_ON:
            setFlashOn(requestBuilder);
            break;
        case FLASH_OFF:
            setFlashOff(requestBuilder);
            break;
    }
}

private void setFlashAuto(CaptureRequest.Builder requestBuilder) {
    requestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE,
            CameraMetadata.CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON_AUTO_FLASH);
}

private void setFlashOn(CaptureRequest.Builder requestBuilder) {
    requestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE,
            CameraMetadata.CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON_ALWAYS_FLASH);
}

private void setFlashOff(CaptureRequest.Builder requestBuilder) {
    requestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE,
            CameraMetadata.CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON);
    requestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE,
            CameraMetadata.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
}
```

How can I handle this situation, when the precapture sequence seemingly can't finish?

Answer (score 0):

After some more research, I couldn't find a reason, why CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON_ALWAYS_FLASH isn't working properly, so I did a workaround. I changed my setFlashOn() method like this

```
private void setFlashOn(CaptureRequest.Builder requestBuilder) {
    requestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE,
            CameraMetadata.CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON);
    requestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE,
            CameraMetadata.FLASH_MODE_SINGLE);
}
```

Maybe it's a problem with the device I'm using, that the setting for always flash isn't working.